# Will resetting my windows 10 keep my activation?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

If I use the windows 10 build-in reset functionality:

- Settings
- Update & security
- Recovery
- Reset this PC

will I keep my windows activation?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know why my question was bad, that's really helpful.

Comment: Your question shows a lack of research on your part.

Comment: @ramhound tell me, do you see anything here? https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=kaNDV-WgJoGy-QXj7YG4Ag#q=Will+resetting+my+windows+10+keep+my+activation

Comment: oh yeah, and how is asking questions on this site not research?

Comment: You asked, the reason you received a downvote, I provided your reason.  Despite the fact I knew you wouldn't agree with my reason, I still provided it, but I won't defend it in the comet section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 uses digital entitlement for activation i.e. it registers your hardware and uses that as your activation key. So as long as you don't make major changes to your hardware such as changing the motherboard, Windows 10 will be activated on your PC.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10

Comment: The link doesn't explicitly point out that hardware is what the digital entitlement is consisted of. Are there other sources that indicates this?

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/regain-free-version-windows-10-changing-computer-hardware

Comment: @George
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ultimate-windows-10-activation-license-faq/

http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-quietly-rewrites-its-activation-rules-for-windows-10/

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2970075/windows/why-you-cant-find-your-product-key-after-upgrading-to-windows-10.html

Comment: that looks legit... guess there's only one way to really find out...

Comment: @George From experience I can say that this does work. I have updated to Windows 10 (in place upgrade), checked that it claimed to be activated, then done a clean install from a USB stick. Windows 10 activated with no intervention at all.

Comment: @Mokubai I've done the same too